# SignalR Client Method is not getting fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm trying to use SignalR 2.4.1 in Asp.Net MVC, i have done sample code thats below,

I am using **WithGenerateProxy** to establish connection.

Hub Method is Called in server side, Received a log in client side

> [18:56:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'SendAsync' on hub 'ChatHub'.

But Client Method **broadcast** is not getting triggered.

What am i missing, below my codes are.

C#

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Broadcast()
        {
            Clients.All.SendAsync("Broadcast");
        }
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SampleSignalR.Startup))]

namespace SampleSignalR
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        }
    }
}
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/SignalR/hubs"></script>

<script>
var connection = $.connection.chatHub;

    $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:64573/signalr";
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    $.connection.hub.connectionSlow(function () {
        console.log("slow connection");
    });
    connection.on("Broadcast", function () {
        console.log("Successs");
    });
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        connection.server.broadcast().done(function () {
            console.log("calling server function");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Packages

```
<package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="1.2.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.JavaScript" version="0.22.9-build00167" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
```

web config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: On a side note, you should look into strongly-typed Hubs for easier method calls, less annoying mistakes and intellisense. Highly recommend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add client method in js like

```
       chat.client.receiveBroadcast = function (data) {
           console.log(data);
        };
```

and in Hub

```
    public void Broadcast()
    {
        Clients.All.receiveBroadcast("Broadcast");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work if you actually want to send it some data:

```
var data = "hello world";
Clients.All.SendAsync("Broadcast", data);
```

For the function to receive data, put in the parameter:

```
connection.on("Broadcast", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: So if you set up a breakpoint on Clients.All.SendAsync, does it get called during debugging?